# How Do I create a search that works in all my views in Django

Tags: django, full-text-search

I currently have a search field in my base.html. heres a snippet

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'posts:list'  %}">HEHTS</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">


          <form method="GET" action=" "  class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="input-group">{% csrf_token %}
              <input type="text" name="q" id="search" placeholder="search" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" class="form-control"
              style="width: 350px">


            <!--<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="search post" value="{{ request.GET.q }}"/>-->
            <!--<input type="submit" value="Search" />-->
        <!--</form>-->

              <ul id="search-results">

              </ul>

            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span style="font-size:1.4em" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> </button>
            </span>
            </div>
          </form>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="{% url 'posts:list'  %}">Home</a></li>
            <!--<li><a href="#">Sewp</a></li>-->
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'posts:create' %}">Create</a></li>
            {% endif %}

          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
</nav>
```

This does not work in my detail.html view. It only works in my post_list.html view heres the views for both of them

```
  def post_detail(request, slug=None):
        instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        if instance.publish > timezone.now().date() or instance.draft:
            if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
                raise Http404

        queryset_list = Post.objects.active()
        query = request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
                    Q(title__icontains=query) |
                    Q(content__icontains=query) |
                    Q(user__first_name__icontains=query) |
                    Q(user__last_name__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()


        share_string = quote_plus(instance.content)
        template = "posts/post_detail.html"
        context = {
            "instance": instance,
            "name": instance.title,
            "share_string": share_string,
            "queryset_list": queryset_list
        }
        return render(request, template, context)


    def post_list(request):
        today = timezone.now().date()
        queryset_list = Post.objects.active()
        if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
            queryset_list = Post.objects.all()

        query = request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
                    Q(title__icontains=query) |
                    Q(content__icontains=query) |
                    Q(user__first_name__icontains=query) |
                    Q(user__last_name__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
        paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 8)
        page_request_var = 'page'
        page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
        try:
            queryset = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            queryset = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        template = "posts/post_list.html"
        name = "user"
        context = {
            "object_list": queryset,
            "name": name,
            "page_request_var": page_request_var,
            "today": today,
        }
        return render(request, template, context)
```

My desired result is to keep things DRY and only have to write the code once and be able to use it in my base.html and it work no matter what view I'm rendering.
How do I go about this, so my blogging application can work in any view? all help or advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be pretty easy. Just give search a dedicated view function and a corresponding url, let's say:

```
url(r'^post-search/$', views.post_search, name='post-search')
```

Then you put your current search form in base.html, with a change in form's action pointing to the `post-search` url:

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'post-search' %}"  class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <!-- same content goes here -->
</form>
```

So now every time you submit this form, it would always go to execute the view function `post_search` and you do the same process and show the result.

[Some explanations about form action attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp).

Comment: thanks for the response. i will try it. If you were a designer, Is this how you would do it? Is this the profesional way?

Comment: I'm not a designer and I wouldn't give people suggestions that I don't know/use.